# Какой SSD поставить в ноутбук Asus Vivobook и что для этого нужно?

Tags: ssd, ноутбук

Всем привет, хотел бы прикупить ssd для ноутбука asusVivobook a512f
вот только не знаю какой подойдет.

Хотел бы SATA SSD, т.к для него есть место и не хочу перекидывать с одного диска на другой данные

вот так выглядит мой ноут в разборе(сорян за пыль, фотка старая )
[image: фото ноута]

подскажите пожалуйста хорошую модель и что мне нужно для этого? корзина и шлейф?

Comment: Я не особо эксперт, но по моему в ноутбуках используются M.2 SSD, а не SATA. Вроде бы он должен находится под той чёрной штукой.

Comment: @ΝNL993, да , я  точно не знаю какой тип ssd используется в ноутбуках, но что вы имели в виду под "должен находится под той чёрной штукой" ??

Comment: @ΝNL993 от ноутбука зависит. У тех, что до 2013 точно не м.2, да и потом не сразу на всех появилось.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy m.2 это физический тип подключения, SATA  - стандарт передачи данных. Они друг друга не исключают. Полно м.2 на стандарте SATA. Может быть даже m.2 с usb3. Нужно смотреть, чтобы было NVMe. Вот это именно скорость передачи данных.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да я тоже все время думал, что м.2 это быстрее, чем САТА, пока пару недель не стал новый диск выбирать

Comment: @Эникейщик на фото видно что нет сата разъема. он должен выпирать минимум на 5 милиметров в посадочном отсеке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для подключения Sata нужно дополнительно прикупить кабель. присоединяется в пустой разъём на плате который рядом с родным ссд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

например должны подойти такие: [алик](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005004883042635.html?sku_id=12000030880436211&spm=a2g2w.productlist.search_results.2.47f31718y9Tdq7), [маркет](https://market.yandex.ru/product--shleif-hdd-dlia-asus-a516-d515-f515-m515-r565-vivobook-x515/1866659453?nid=26895910&show-uid=16978748035826771483916003&context=search&text=hdd%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%20asus&uniqueId=857629&own-cards=857629%3A102030759020&sku=102030759020&cpc=WBvbvXJdDXI0xG8DtOPy9IBgeFvsMWcjDy7oiaXrL1fKefluhdvPk_mwaRtuX_NlbEjQrSSBtoU1RpCW28HQA1o5-lcHMm17XZ7dGHyKXYM7rEAdWJI6IHsGRwq5DzdHpsmLEK_PGSLNX5vj79PxClptJ6FxJk5pRJhDWT2YKskYgcw2GcQjpqtHF_f5hS9_oCm-bESRLG7MBofwXjJttsiUGavkcc5BkOucg1Vejih7gIQEYnKVcxH9v-6RQ5luxql9M5n1bjf7mYIkJRvslQ%2C%2C&do-waremd5=2-LgUZ_6nzDNxkLfF7N0Ow&sponsored=1&rs=eJwlkLFqwlAYha-EvoAVhE55hk4tVbm4pljboaPNUFx8CQ2kLq4SWjpEcHN2sE0wi6VLoF06Xyi-gavQnK_L4XD-85__3Hseef3armbSQ6tC85BVOJ63KwwTKf6vuFvmUk7BM5QnTcNX-f0EJZJS5FKKD9K60u1MW75l9xIevYlf42xwy5HzKHQreewLCfdk3tBkIqepC9PRVnx9pbbf4J7mt3Lao9A9k_wuni7ExyVXyA9jmkwzWtFzIKX4UZr94kX_U37AnnSU8EnzDbcuaOtxpSf0Y-0acsKAtJImQzobnAF97lB4ddFs_wGwcYsH)

Comment: на фото не хватает разъёма куда втыкать. нужен такой кабель.

Comment: пустой конектор рядом с м2 ссд

Comment: Да, в этом нойтбуке  действительно сата на кабеле висит https://www.insidemylaptop.com/how-to-disassemble-asus-vivobook-15-f512-x512/

Comment: @Эникейщик, написано, что это hdd кабель, а для ssd подойдет? я уже давно ищу и не могу найти резиновую корзину для диска, если есть такая возможность, то можешь закинуть ссылку пожалуйста?

Comment: подойдет, это простой сата кабель. насчет корзины я бы не парился если ставишь ссд. он легкий и не крутится - поэтому достаточно на 2х-сторонний скотч чтоб не болтался